# Manifold coordinate basis

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

> For every non-compact manifold $M$, there exists a sequence $U_i$ of coordinate charts,such that $\bigcup U_i = M$, $U_i \cap U_{i+1} \neq \emptyset$, and given any $K \subset M$ compact, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $n > N \implies U_n \cap K = \emptyset$.

I need to prove this. So what I do know, is that there does exist a compact exhaustion $K_i$ of every such manifold. I also know that if you give me any two points, I can find $V_1, ...,V_N$ so that $V_1$ contains the first point, $V_N$ contains the last point, and $V_i \cap V_{i+1}$ is non-empty.

I know that it can be done using these two lemmas, however I need some guidance on how to use the exhaustion here. The following idea comes to mind :

Pick points $p_i \in K_{i+1} \backslash K_i$, and $p_1 \in K_1$. Connect these via coordinate charts using the lemma above. However, I can't get these to cover the entire manifold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: cover your first compact $K_0$ by finitely many coordinate domains. Then inductively cover $K_{i+1} \backslash \mathring{K_i}$ by finitely many coordinate domains, and then use your lemma connecting the $p_i$.

Comment: How do I ensure, that in the cover for the first compact $K_0$, is covered by open sets such that $U_i \cap U_{i+1}$ is non-empty?

Comment: good point. you can start with any compact in your exhaustion, so you may as well start with one that is actually contained in just one coordinate domain

Comment: Oh ,yes, that is very smart! Fine, I will think and get back to you.

Comment: I  modified  your hint, and got the right answer. However, I must admit that the proof was very technical, and much longer than  I had expected it to be initially.